# Binding not exhaustive warning in SML/NJ but not in F# for same pattern

Tags: f#, sml, smlnj

The SML/NJ code below results in a binding not exhaustive warning for "val Grove(whatTree) = glen". The F# equivalent code produces no warning. Why?

Standard ML of New Jersey (32-bit) v110.99.2 [built: Tue Sep 28 13:04:14 2021]:

```
datatype tree = Oak|Elem|Maple|Spruce|Fir|Pine|Willow
datatype vegetable = Carrot|Zucchini|Tomato|Cucumber|Lettuce
datatype grain = Wheat|Oat|Barley|Maize
datatype plot = Grove of tree|Garden of vegetable|Field of grain|Vacant
val glen = Grove(Oak)
val Grove(whatTree) = glen
```

F# 6.0.0 Warning Level 5:

```
type Tree = Oak|Elem|Maple|Spruce|Fir|Pine|Willow
type Vegetable = Carrot|Zucchini|Tomato|Cucumber|Lettuce
type Grain = Wheat|Oat|Barley|Maize
type Plot = Grove of Tree|Garden of Vegetable|Field of Grain|Vacant
let glen = Grove(Oak)
let Grove(whatTree) = glen
```

[Why binding not exhaustive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60807666/why-binding-not-exhaustive)  The accepted answer to this related question gives me some hints about my question. The SML warning is indicating redundant code. So, I'll assume the F# compiler writers did not deem this case worthy of a warning.

Comment: What are you expecting the compiler to be checking?

Comment: I'm expecting the F# and SML/NJ compilers to produce the same warning or both of them produce no warning.

Comment: I've updated answer to show how to perform binding instead of creating function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This F# code `let Grove(whatTree) = glen` is ambiguous because it can be interpreted as value binding with deconstruction or function.

In first case syntax is

```ml
let pattern = expr
```

In seconds case syntax is

```ml
let name pattern-list = expr
```

Since F# supports shadowing, it's legal to create new function. But SML seems to have different opinion on this and decides to bind value.

In the end: code in SML and F# does different things, that's why there's no warnings

---

To actually perform binding, left side of `let` should parenthesized:

```ml
let (Grove(whatTree)) = glen
```

It produces warning: `C:\stdin(6,5): warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value 'Field (_)' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).`